# F# async - difference between two structure

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Is there a difference between writing something like this:

```
MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> async {
    let rec loop bugs =
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        let res = //something
        loop res
    loop []})
```

And writing it like this:

```
MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
    let rec loop bugs = async {
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        let res = //something
        do! loop res }
    loop [])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example is not valid F# code, because `let!` can only be used immediately inside computation expression. In your example, you're using it in an ordinary function - its body is not a computation expression, so `let!` is not allowed in that position.

To make it valid, you'd need to wrap the body of the `loop` function inside `async`:

```
MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> async {
    let rec loop bugs = async {
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        let res = //something
        return! loop res }
    return! loop []})
```

You can keep the outer `async { .. }` block in the snippet as well - then you just need to use `return!` to call your `loop` function instead of just returning it (but other than that there is no significant difference now).

Note that I used `return!` instead of `do!` - this actually makes a difference, because `return!` represents a tail-call, which means that the rest of the current body can be discarded. If you use `do!` then the async allocates something like a stack frame in the heap, so using `do!` in a recursive looping function leaks memory.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why they didn't see if it works first.

Comment: And here I was wondering why when I got home all my apps had crashed with my system saying out of virtual memory!

Thanks Tomas!

Comment: @ChaosPandion Very good point, I was playing with code that didn't compile for another reason and just assumed what I was looking at would work - feel free to vote down the question but Tomas' answer was pretty useful anyway.

Comment: @David - I really was just curious.

Comment: @David - Glad that the answer helped (with a more important issue :-)).